# Peer not authenticated when login on publisher or store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When logging into the /publisher or /store, I get the "Peer not authenticated" error.

To give more context, I created a new keystore and imported its .pem certificate into the client-trustore.jks and finally updated the SSL keystore configuration to use this new one, as written here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products#Configuring%20keystores%20for%20SSL%20connections

WSO2 Log with SSL Debug enabled:

```
%% Invalidated:  [Session-11, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384]
http-nio-9443-exec-25, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-25, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-9443-exec-25, called closeSocket()
http-nio-9443-exec-25, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
http-nio-9443-exec-25, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
http-nio-9443-exec-45, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-9443-exec-45, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-45, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-45, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-45, called closeOutbound()
http-nio-9443-exec-45, closeOutboundInternal()
http-nio-9443-exec-45, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
http-nio-9443-exec-45, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2

TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-10 15:03:32,866]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater}
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-03-10 15:03:32,898]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://<serverPublicIP>:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:450)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:276)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:186)
```

The keytool commands I used:

```
// Create the keystore
$ keytool -genkey -alias custom -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore custom.jks -dname "CN=<myhostdomain>, OU=Home,O=Home,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" -storepass wso2carbon -keypass wso2carbon

// Export the new keystore certificate
$ keytool -export -alias custom -keystore custom.jks -file custom.pem

// Import the new certificate into the client-truststore
$ keytool -import -alias custom -file custom.pem -keystore client-truststore.jks -storepass wso2carbon
```

#### Product Version:

APIM 2.6 (not using IS as Key Manager, just the stock WSO2 API Manager)

Comment: You will have to enable ssl debug logs and find the reason, as `peer not authenticted` is a very general error. See https://medium.com/@dilsimchandrasena/how-to-enable-ssl-debug-logs-for-wso2-products-6de7276ffe10

Comment: @Bee thank you, will do and update the question with more details

Comment: Looks like the cert was not installed to the client trust store properly. Can you try again?

Comment: @Bee Ok I tried again. Deleted the previous certificate/keystore and recreated, then I restarted the server: same error unfortunally. I also updated the question with the commands I used to create and import the certificate. Do you see anything bad?

Comment: I reinstalled wso2 from scratch and now it is working, even after adding the certificate. Not sure which bad configuration caused this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consistently reproduced the issue on a clean installation. The problem was that I enabled the H2 database visualization in the browser, by changing this config in the **carbon.xml** (it was commented):

```
<H2DatabaseConfiguration>
        <property name="web" />
        <property name="webPort">8082</property>
        <property name="webAllowOthers" />
```

For some reason, this causes the **Peer not authenticated** error, when logging to the publisher or store.